# remove old app icons from avd home screen

Tags: android-emulator

I have created several sample apps for an Android virtual device. I have deleted these apps from the Eclipse java perspective, but they remain on the Android avd home screen.

How do I remove these app icons from the Android avd home screen?

Answer (score 3):

If you mean the shortcuts:

Same way as on a phone.  Long click an icon and drag it to the trash can symbol which should appear.

If you mean deleting the app entirely:

Also same way as on a phone.  I think it's something like Menu->Settings->Manage Applications.

Answer (score 1):

Though too late to respond, but hopefully it will be useful for someone in future.

On the latest Android version 4 you can do this **Menu - > Manage Application** and then double click on application which you want to delete, it will ask for confirmation whether you want to uninstall or stop (if running). Choose whichever option you want.